# Jacobian-Free Newton-Krylov vs explicitly forming jacobian in DG

Tags: petsc, discontinuous-galerkin, jacobian

For a given discontinuous galerkin (DG) implementation for Navier-Stokes, targeting 10,000 to 1,000,000 4th order cells in 3D, I'm using PETSc's suite of linear/non-linear solvers on the back-end. It seems to me that there are two broad methods of implicitly solving the discretization. One can explicitly form the Jacobian in a sparse format and use whatever tools are available to solve it, or use a Jacobian-Free Newton-Krylov method that approximates the jacobian-vector products by evaluating the right-hand-side by finite differences. Advantages and disadvantages I see of each:

*Explicit Jacobian*

- Con - Requires a large amount of memory (precisely how much? can I do this with <100GB total memory?)
- Con - Requires writing code to evaluate the Jacobian and store it
- Pro - Allows the use of black-box preconditioners already present in PETSc

*Jacobian-Free Newton-Krylov*

- Pro - Minimal memory needs
- Con - Unknown how often to re-linearize or what finite difference steps to use, how often to restart, etc.
- Con - must write own preconditioners.

I'd like some input from those more familiar with these methods as to the advantages and disadvantages of them. Am I right to assume the explicit jacobian would be much faster?

Comment: Related: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/19152/caveats-of-hessian-free-method (Even better: use Jacobian-free Newton-Krylov with discretized analytical derivatives, aka adjoint and tangent solves.)